# I have error while running my code in code block, I am using c and c++

Tags: c++, warnings

I have a problem with my c++ code.

This is my code.

2 cpp files( main.cpp, function.cpp)
2 header files(1 is for program description, 1 is for libraries and function prototypes)

These four files are in the same folder with a simple name. In that folder, there is a project file also.

I made a project from Codeblock 12.11 version, erased the default main.cpp in the project.

And from the project bar which is in the top of code block, I added two cpp files above, but not the two header files. It was my professor's instruction.

I included two header files in the main.cpp and included one header file( which has libraries) in the function.cpp.

When I ran it, it built and ran fine. However when I sent my project to my professor, he couldn't run the project. He said that the code exists immediately, and nothing happens.

In my codeblock from windows, the IDE compiler program where I made my project, I couldn't find any error.
However when I tried the same project from my mac(I have 2 computers)using codeblock, There is no error, but a warning appears like this.

warning: ld: warning: ignoring file obj/Debug/function.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x4c 0x 1 0x c 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x ....0 0x 0) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): obj/Debug/function.oignoring file obj....

=== Build failed: 0 error(s). 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 send(s)) ===

I don't know where to fix.

This is my main.cpp.

```
#include "Project_Description.h"
#include "Project_Header.h"

int main()
{
int score[100];
int highest=0;
int sum=0;
int n=0;
   double id;
   char y;
   cout<<"Are you ready for the quiz? If yes, please type Y or y."<<endl;
   cin>>y;
   while(y=='y'||y=='Y')
   {

    score[n]=0;
    cout<<"Enter your 8 digits student ID number: ";
    cin>>id;
    while(id>=100000000||id<10000000) // this while loop is to prevent wrong ID numbers.
    {
        cout<<"Sorry, your ID number is incorrect."<<"We need 8 digits student ID number,   
    please retype your ID number"<<endl;
        cin>>id;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"In this quiz, each question is 2 points,so the total score is 26."<<endl;
    cout<<"****************"<<endl;
    score[n]=quizs(score[n]);
//call the return function quizs
    sum+=score[n];
    if (score[n]>highest)
        highest=score[n];


    cout<<"Your final score is: "<<score[n]<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
"<<endl;


    cout<<"Is any other student? If yes, please enter y or Y.\nIf no,enter any other     
letter.";
    cin>>y;
    if(y=='y'||y=='Y')//every new student should enter 'y' to enter their information.
    {
        cout<<"Are you ready for the quiz? If yes, please type Y or y."<<endl;
        cin>>y;
    }
    n++;

}
cout<<"There are "<<n<<" students who took the exam!"<<endl;          
// line 48, 49, 50 are shown after the last student.

cout <<"The average score of every students is "<< sum/n<<endl;
cout<<"The best score is "<<highest<<endl;
return 0;//end the program.
}
```

and this is the function.cpp

```
#include "Project_Header.h"


int quizs(int score)
/*in this function, student gonna start the quizs, and this function will call function              
question1 to question13 to test students.*/
{
double answer[14];//real answer
double stanswer[14];//student's answer
for(int i=1; i <=14; i++)//i=question number
{
    if(i==1)
    question1(answer, stanswer);// question1
    if(i==2)
    question2(answer, stanswer);//question 2
    if(i==3)
    question3(answer, stanswer);//question 3
    if(i==4)
    question4(answer, stanswer);//question 4
    if(i==5)
    question5(answer, stanswer);//question 5
    if(i==6)
    question6(answer, stanswer);//question 6
     if(i==7)
    question7(answer, stanswer); //question 7
     if(i==8)
    question8(answer, stanswer); //question 8
     if(i==9)
    question9(answer, stanswer); //question 9
     if(i==10)
    question10(answer, stanswer); //question 10

     if(i==11)
    question11(answer, stanswer); //question 11

    if(i==12)
        question12(answer, stanswer); //question 12
    if(i==13)
        question13(answer, stanswer); //question 13


    if (stanswer[i-1]==answer[i-1])//compare student's answer and the correct answer.
    score=score +2;//when you get one more question right, add 2 points.
  }

return score;// return the final score to main function.
}
void question1(double *answer, double *stanswer)// questions
{
cout<<"Question1:";
answer[0]=4;
cout<<"1+3= ";
cin >>stanswer[0];
}
void question2(double *answer, double *stanswer)
{
cout<<"Question2:";
answer[1]=780;
cout<<"26*30=";
cin>>stanswer[1];
}
void question3(double *answer, double *stanswer)
{
cout<<"Question3:";
answer[2]=4;
cout<<"simplify ";
cout<<"36/9=";
cin>>stanswer[2];
}
void question4(double *answer, double *stanswer)
{
cout<<"Question4:";
answer[3]=1;
cout<<"Find the remander of ";
cout<<"100/9.  Type your answer: ";
cin>>stanswer[3];
}
void question5(double *answer, double *stanswer)
{
cout<<"Question5:";
answer[4]=7;
cout<<"-4-(-11)= ";
cin>>stanswer[4];
}
void question6(double *answer, double *stanswer)
{
cout<<"Question6:";
answer[5]=40;
cout<<"4*(3+7)=";
cin>>stanswer[5];
}

 void question7(double * answer, double *stanswer)
{
cout<<"Question7:";
answer[6]=120;
cout<<"What is the value of 5 factorial?"<<endl<<"5!= ";
cin>>stanswer[6];
}

void question8(double *answer, double * stanswer)
{
cout<<"Question8:";
answer[7]=38;
cout<<"What is the absolute value of (34-72)?"<<endl<<"|34-72|= ";
cin>>stanswer[7];
}

void question9(double *answer, double * stanswer)
{
 char s[99];
 cout << "Question9:";
 char a[6]={"2x+19"};
 cout<<"What is derivative of (x^2+19x)?"<<endl;
 cin.ignore(256,'\n');
// cin.ignore works with cin.getline,  cin.ignore is used to prevent errors.
 cin.getline(s,99);
// cin the student's answer, this 's' is 'stanswer', '99' is for space.
 if(strcmp(a,s)==0)
//strcmp(a,s)==0 means string'a' and 's' are same, strcmp(a,s)==-1 means string 'a' and    
//'s'are different.
 {
    answer[8]=0;
//if the student get the correct answer, we can make answer and stanswer be same, so in    
//quiz function, the student can get the point.
    stanswer[8]=0;
// so these two '0's can be any numbers, but in like this way-->answer[8]=2;
//stanswer[8]=2;
 }

}
void question10(double *answer, double *stanswer)
{
cout << "Question10:";
answer[9]=10;
cout<<"What is the square root of 100"<< endl;
cin>>stanswer[9];
}
void question11(double *answer, double *stanswer)
{
char s[99];
cout<<"Questions 11:";
char a[9]={"x^5-cosx"};
cout<<"What is the integral of 5x^4+sinx?"<<endl;
cin.ignore(256,'\n'); 
// cin.ignore works with cin.getline,  cin.ignore is used to prevent errors.

cin.getline(s,99);  
// cin the student's answer, this 's' is 'stanswer', '99' is for space.

if(strcmp(a,s)==0)   
//strcmp(a,s)==0 means string'a' and 's' are same, strcmp(a,s)==-1 
//means string 'a' and 's' are different.
{
    answer[10]=0;   
//if the student get the correct answer, we can make answer and 
//stanswer be same, so in quiz function, the student can get the point.
    stanswer[10]=0;  // so these two '0's can be any numbers.
}
}
void question12(double *answer, double *stanswer )
{
cout<<"Quetion 12:"<<endl;
int matrix[2][2]={2,3,1,2}; // double array, matrix looks like double array
answer[11]=1;
cout<< "Find the det of the matrix:"<<endl<<"|"<<matrix[0][0]<<" "<<matrix[0][1]<<"| "                          
<<endl<<"|"<<matrix[1][0]<<" "<<matrix[1][1]<<"|"<<endl;
cin>>stanswer[11]; // det of the matrix = ad-bc of the matrix (a b)
}
//                                                              (c d)
void question13(double *answer, double *stanswer)
{
cout<<"Question 13:"<<endl;
char a[13]={"2x(x+8)(x-6)"};
cout<<"Factoring: 2x^3+4x^2-96x"<<endl;
char s[99]; // I wrote 99 because the user might type a long answer
cin.ignore(256, '\n');  
// cin.ignore works with cin.getline,  cin.ignore is used to prevent errors.
 cin.getline(s,99);  
// cin the student's answer, this 's' is 'stanswer', '99' is for space.

  if(strcmp(a,s)==0)   
//strcmp(a,s)==0 means string'a' and 's' are same, strcmp(a,s)==-1 means string 'a' and    
//'s' are different.
 {
    answer[12]=0;  
//if the student get the correct answer, we can make answer and stanswer be same, so in   
//quiz function, the student can get the point.

        stanswer[12]=0;  // so these two '0's can be any numbers.
    }
 }
```

the description file's name is Project_Description.h
it is not added in the project, but in the same folder with the project and two cpp files.
it starts as

/*

and end as

*/

in side the comment there are descriptions of the program. 
and nothing is in the outside of the comment.

There is another header file which has prototypes, libraries in it.

The file name is Project_Header.h

It looks like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>


using namespace std;
int quizs (int score);
//in this function, student gonna start the quizs, and this function will call quation1-13                
//functions to test student
void question1(double *answer, double *stanswer);
void question2(double *answer, double *stanswer);
void question3(double *answer, double *stanswer);
void question4(double *answer, double *stanswer);
void question5(double *answer, double *stanswer);
void question6(double *answer, double *stanswer);
void question7(double *answer, double *stanswer);
void question8(double *answer, double *stanswer);
void question9(double *answer, double *stanswer);
void question10(double *answer, double *stanswer);
void question11(double *answer, double *stanswer);
void question12(double *answer, double *stanswer);
void question13(double *answer, double *stanswer);
```

This is the end.

Can anybody help me find the error and fix it?

Comment: Your title implies you are mixing C modules with C++ modules, is this true?

Comment: On an unrelated note, please learn about structs and classes. This code is begging to be organized in an array.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you are trying to link an object file you compiled on your windows machine on your mac. This is not possible due to different hardware architectures. Try deleting the .o files in your project and recompile on your mac from scratch.

In general there is a second problem with your files that CodeBlocks seems to fix somehow but it would cause problems if you compiled from a terminal for example: function.cpp is never compiled, which would cause linking errors because the linker will not find the code for the functions you implemented in this file.

One fix would be to include function.cpp in your main.cpp file, a second one to compile those two files separately with -c option (g++ -c main.cpp and g++ -c functions.cpp) and link them afterwards (g++ main.o functions.o -o main).

Hope that helps.